# IntelliJ IDEA: Running multiple applications with one click

Tags: intellij-idea, workflow

My application consists of 5 separate modules - web application, static web resources, 3 Java applications communicating through message queues.

My current workflow is to manually select them one by one from right corner select box and click Run or Debug button. This is especially annoying when I switch between SCM branches several times a day and I need to re-run everything.

Is there a *simple* way to configure IntelliJ to run all of them with one click?

Comment: Did you try [Multirun plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248)?

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising.